# Is it possible to load some files to ecs fargate ephemeral storage

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to load my application on ecs fargate along with a MySQL container. As a part of testing I need to load some data in MySQL container from SQL files. Since it's part of testing I am not looking for persistent storage.

I can load sample data via docker-compose in the following way in my local system.

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: somedb
  volumes:
    - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Is it possible to copy these sql files to ecs ephemeral storage? As a workaround I have created a separate MySQL docker image that already contains all these sample data. But this creates another problem, I need to create separate images for specific microservices.

Comment: if it helps, docker-entrypoint-initdb.d can contain scripts.

Comment: I already have *.sql files under data directory as specified in the local docker-compose. In local it works as expected. I am trying to understand if it's possible to initialize db's in ecs using these *.sql files

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of EFS with Fargate, you can dump data to be load to sql in EFS and mount this EFS on Fargate on any desired path.

[Fargate EFS Feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-supports-efs/)